# Resulting SQL from a prepared statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, prepared-statement, executenonquery

I'm using Prepared Statement in Visual Studio 2012 c#.

I use `using(SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())` and `preparedStmt.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Is it possible, after executing `ExecuteNonQuery()` or preferably before it, retrieve the resulting SQL that it generates?

I know that prepared statements are ran directly on the DBMS and aren't a SQL string built on the application server. But I need to debug some SQL statements directly on DB as plain SQL.

When `ExecuteNonQuery()` brings an Exception, it has only the error message, not the SQL that was executed, and I'm having trouble to debug without the proper SQL.

Comment: Use Sql Profiler to get the exact queries.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MS Sql Server? If so the standard approach for trapping an sql statement for debugging is to use Sql Profiler.

Comment: Thanks I'll try MSSQL Profiler. I must first get permission to use it on the server.